# Iceberg table snapshots not expired

Tags: apache-spark, hive, google-cloud-dataproc, apache-iceberg

I'm using Dataroc Metastore, Dataproc Batch and Pyspark. Although I'm using GCP, I beleive this is general Apache Iceberg question.

I run My spark job and created Iceberg trips table with automatic snapshot expiration in 1 hour `history.expire.max-snapshot-age-ms=3600000` and wrote from content of CSV file into table.

```
conf = (
    SparkConf()
    .setAppName('read_from_iceberg')
    .set('spark.sql.extensions', 'org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions')
    .set('spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog', 'org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog')
    .set('spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.type', 'hive')
    .set(f'spark.sql.catalog.dev', 'org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog')
    .set(f'spark.sql.catalog.dev.type', 'hive')
    .set(f'spark.sql.warehouse.dir', lake_bucket)
)
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

schema = StructType([
    StructField("vendor_id", LongType(), True),
    StructField("trip_id", LongType(), True),
    StructField("trip_distance", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("fare_amount", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("store_and_fwd_flag", StringType(), True)
])
# Create database if not exists
spark.sql("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS dev.lakehouse")

# Create table if doesn't exist.
# df = spark.createDataFrame([], schema)
df.writeTo("dev.lakehouse.trips").partitionedBy("vendor_id")
 .tableProperty('format-version', '2')
 .tableProperty("history.expire.max-snapshot-age-ms","3600000").createOrReplace())

df3 = spark.read.option("delimiter", ",").schema(schema).option("header", True).csv(
    "gs://my-super-bucket/csv-input/bulk/*")

df3.write.mode('append').format("iceberg").insertInto("dev.lakehouse.trips")
```

I repeated batch execution for a several times and as the result I have 45 millions objects from writes.

```
+---------+
| count(1)|
+---------+
|450000000|
+---------+
```

Now I would like to see the table history.

```
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM dev.lakehouse.trips4.history").show()
```

And the result is the following:

```
+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|     made_current_at|        snapshot_id|          parent_id|is_current_ancestor|
+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|2023-11-08 09:05:...|3365635318905728444|               null|               true|
|2023-11-08 09:07:...|8818173850344394660|3365635318905728444|               true|
|2023-11-08 09:18:...|7080281147456503211|8818173850344394660|               true|
|2023-11-08 09:26:...|1124704647664806615|7080281147456503211|               true|
|2023-11-08 09:43:...|1410379929547885531|1124704647664806615|               true|
|2023-11-08 09:44:...|2828602979849095888|1410379929547885531|               true|
|2023-11-08 11:59:...|3836167930220261494|2828602979849095888|               true|
|2023-11-08 12:09:...|7872321137982208330|3836167930220261494|               true|
+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Although, the expiration is set to one hour, I still see all other snapshots that supposed to be removed.

I know that I can always use

```
spark.sql("CALL dev.system.expire_snapshots('dev.lakehouse.trips4', TIMESTAMP '2023-11-08 11:00:00.000', 1)")
```

and this will remove older then a given timestamp, but should't it be done automatic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expired Iceberg table snapshots are not automatically deleted. The [doc](https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/maintenance/#expire-snapshots) says

> Snapshots accumulate until they are expired by the `expireSnapshots` operation. Regularly expiring snapshots is recommended to delete data files that are no longer needed.

The config [`history.expire.max-snapshot-age-ms`](https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/configuration/#table-behavior-properties) is

> Default max age of snapshots to keep on the table and all of its branches while expiring snapshots.

The code `spark.sql("CALL dev.system.expire_snapshots('dev.lakehouse.trips4', TIMESTAMP '2023-11-08 11:00:00.000', 1)")` you show is the [Spark SQL extension for expiring snapshots](https://github.com/apache/iceberg/issues/1597).